# Match at least one character and zero or more new lines

Tags: javascript, regex

I want my code to find string that contains at least one character and new line(zero or more).

`[\s\S]+` doesn't work for me because it also matches only new lines (without any character).

Comment: What do you mean by character? What are the allowed characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you are looking for is

```
/\w+\n*/
```

This matches any alphanumeric character and `_` 1 or more times and then new line characters 0 or more times

See few of the examples

```
var pattern = /\w+\n*/
console.log("a".match(pattern));
console.log("aaa".match(pattern));
console.log("a\n".match(pattern));
console.log("a\n\n\n".match(pattern));
console.log("a\nb".match(pattern));
console.log("\na\nb".match(pattern));
```

**Output**

```
[ 'a', index: 0, input: 'a' ]
[ 'aaa', index: 0, input: 'aaa' ]
[ 'a\n', index: 0, input: 'a\n' ]
[ 'a\n\n\n', index: 0, input: 'a\n\n\n' ]
[ 'a\n', index: 0, input: 'a\nb' ]
[ 'a\n', index: 1, input: '\na\nb' ]
```

Comment: This will not match "?\n".

Comment: @Jongware Yup because the definition of character is ambiguous I think

Comment: But it won't work for `console.log("a\nb".match(pattern));` or `console.log("\na\nb".match(pattern));`

That's what I want to do!